# Почему иногда код, расположенный ниже, выполняется первее? Python

Tags: python

**Проблема:** имеется простенький код, нажатие клавиши клавиатуры с помощью библиотеки `pyautogui`, а после код проигрывания звука из библиотеки `winsound`. При запуске кода, через раз выполняется код для winsound, а код для нажатия клавиши вообще не выполняется. Частично решил это тем, что поставил задержку `time.sleep(1)` между нажатием и проигрыванием звука, теперь такое происходит реже.

Скажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

**Код:**

```
...
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
self.music_player_object.play_start_process_music() # Функция, проигрывающая звук.
...
```

Comment: код бы увидеть было бы неплохо

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, извините, добавил.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что код иногда не выполняется?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, потому что выделенный текст должен скопироваться, но этого не происходит. То-есть crtl c не работает.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, при работе скрипта обратите внимание на раскладку клавиатуры, проблема может быть в том, что "с" у вас латинская в хоткее, но подаётся кириллица.

Comment: @Dmitry У меня была такая же мысль, но вроде копирование и при включённой русской раскладке работает. Хотя проверить эту теорию стоит всё-равно.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, комбинация в ОС работает исправно, но тут Вы явно подаёте к функцию символ латинский или из кириллицы. Могу быть не прав.

Comment: Всем спасибо, проблема оказалась в самой функции pyautogui, где нужно было указать атрибут interval = 0.1